# Looking for a sci-fi duology (I think)

Tags: story-identification, space

The series should have been written in the late eighties or nineties.  Space opera involving a large mercenary space force...star commander or similar was the title of the main protagonist.  Kidnapped to a planet and force to work in the sewers, he is found by his second in command...who is a female.  I remember part of this scene, which ends with him killing someone in "the most painful way he knew."

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You might be able to improve this question by going through the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: It sounds like Miles Vorkosigan

Comment: @DannyMcG It could be close, especially if bits of different stories get mixed up, like conflating being kidnapped in London's tidal works (*Brothers in Arms*) with being put to cleaning drains on Kyril Island (*The Vor Game*).  But it's not a duology; by the 90s there were at least 3 books out IIRC.  You might post it as an answer anyway.

Comment: I think this was a subplot in W. Michael Gear's *Forbidden Borders* trilogy.

Answer (score 4):

Novels featuring mercenary companies seem to have been popular in the 1980s, and not just in science fiction (see Glen Cook's *Black Company* novels for a contemporaneous fantasy example), but not many had a woman second-in-command.  Among the *star-faring* mercenary company *series* in that time-frame that I'm familiar with (including *Hammer's Slammers*, *Falkenberg's Legion*, Dalmas' *The Regiment*, Dickson's *Dorsai* and Rosenberg's *Metzadan Mercenary Corps*) I can think of only 2 with a female second:  the "Grey Death Legion" from Michael Stackpole's *Battletech* novels and the "Dendarii Mercenaries" in Lois McMaster Bujold's *Vorkosigan* novels.

You may be partially remembering ***Brothers in Arms*** (1989), which was the second (published order) novel featuring Miles Vorkosigan as the protagonist.  He is the nominal admiral (self-designated) of the Dendarii Free Mercenary Fleet, and also a lieutenant in the intelligence service of the Barrayaran Imperium.  The story takes place on or around Earth, mostly in London in the aftermath of the events of "The Borders of Infinity" (1987).  In the course of the story Miles is captured by Komarran rebels and rescued by Elli Quinn and the final confrontation takes place in the Thames Tidal Barrier (somewhat more grand than at present) where they rescue his cousin Ivan from a pump and then hide in it themselves.  The description of the dark, slimy insides could be what you recall as a sewer.

[image: Original paperback cover of "Brothers in Arms"]

Note that of all the mercenary SF series I can think of from the 1980s and 1990s this is the only one where the hero commands a mercenary space fleet.  The part that gives me the most pause is your last line; Miles tries very hard, improbably hard even, not to kill people and never takes pleasure in making people suffer.